# Como importar arquivos utilizando REGEX?

Tags: python, regex, script

Boa Tarde Pessoal, Tudo bem?

Estou com uma dúvida em regex em python.

Desejo criar um script para abrir arquivos sem informar seu formato podendo ser

pdf, txt, jpg, png, entre outros... Porém, desejo apenas especificar o nome da imagem, sem informar seu formato(informando o formato dentro do regex). Alguma dica de solução?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode criar um pattern com o nome desejado, e as extensões possíveis. 
Supondo que você deseja buscar por *imagem.png*, ou *imagem.jpg* ou *imagem.gif* dentro de c:/teste

```
import re
import os
padrao = r'imagem\.(png|jpg|gif)'
base_dir = 'c:/teste/'
for arquivo in os.listdir():
    if re.match(padrao, arquivo):
        with open(base_dir + arquivo) as reader:
            print(reader.read())
```

Comment: Obrigado Moises, deu certo, porém, não consigo ler o arquivo, ele apenas exibe o formato, existe a possibilidade dele exibir? caso seja um .txt ou .pdf?
Fiz a seguinte alteração no código : 

import re
import os
padrao = r'atendimento\.(png|jpg|gif|txt|pdf)'
for arquivo in os.listdir('C:/Users/v_lop/Desktop/Importar/'):
    if re.match(padrao, arquivo):
        print(arquivo.file.read())  # no read ele informa o erro  : 'str' object has no attribute 'file'

Comment: no exemplo eu usei print apenas para exibir o nome do arquivo encontrado. Se você quer ler o conteúdo deste arquivo, vai precisar trocar o print por open(). Editado para sua compreensão

Comment: Obrigado amigo, funcionou!